# How to find related view/ code with debug view hierarchy in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I remember for UIKit we could see the related viewcontroller name in `debug Navigator`, but with SwiftUI, how could we do the same. For instance, I get a project from others and want to know where the code or view definition is on the page.

[image]

Comment: @Sweeper I want to know where is the file/struct view declared this page.

Comment: You can do it the same way as before - look at the view hierarchy and find the non-built-in view that is closest to the root.

Comment: Like it could be created in ContentView or other xxxView, but how could I know it from debug view hierarchy.

Comment: Nop, that is what I need, if I could know the class name or struct name, then I can find the code. Sorry for this poor question.

Comment: Well then what do you mean by "Like it could be created in ContentView or other xxxView"? What's so difficult? Can you show one of your failed attempts?

Comment: No no, it is just my eye is missing that line of 'ContentView' in the left panel. Never mind. I would close this question. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Taras HostingView -> ContentView is what I need. I just miss that before. Please help to close this op, it is not an issue.

Comment: @ZhouHaibo for me it's still up in the air